# Dynamically Centering Webpage Content When Page Is Not Full

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that has a vertical sticky menu on the left in a div. The content, centered on the page horizontally, is in an additional div. Both the menu div and the content div are in a third div, centered on the page.

Sometimes the content div has more content than fits on a page, but sometimes, it doesn't. In those cases where the content does not fill the page, I would like the content to be vertically centered on the page (example [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch/publications)). However, when the content goes past the page, I would like the content to be justified to the top as usual (example [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch/)).

The default, for when the content is past the page, works fine. How do I have the content vertically center when it doesn't fill the page?

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
}

a {
    color: #6FBD31;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.sticky-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
}

div.sticky-menu li {
    background-position: 100%;
    padding-right: .6em;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

div.sticky-menu {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 30%;
}

div.sticky-menu a:link {
    color: #D8D8D8;
}

div.sticky-menu a:visited {
    color: #D8D8D8;
}

div.sticky-menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

div.sticky-menu a:active {
    color: #D8D8D8;
}

div.wrapp {
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div.content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
```

And my HTML for the home page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Allie Saupp&eacute;</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sticky-menu">
                <ul id="menu-items">
                    <li class="item" id="home">
                        <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item" id="research">
                        <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch/research">Research</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item" id="publications">
                        <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch/publications">Publications</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item" id="teaching">
                        <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~aterrell/websiteScratch/teaching">Teaching</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapp">
                <p>
                I am a Ph.D. candidate at the <a href="http://www.wisc.edu">University of Wisconsin-Madison</a> where I am part of the <a
                href="http://www.hci.cs.wisc.edu">Human-Computer Interaction Lab</a> in the <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu">Computer Sciences department</a>. I work
                with my advisor, <a href="http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~bilge">Bilge Mutlu</a>, to design more effective collaborative behaviors to enable robots to work
                alongside humans.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

I would like the paragraph to be centered vertically (e.g., roughly equal space on the top and bottom).

Comment: I found another great website you should check out http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center This would really help your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I edited the divs so that it will hopefully display how you would like.

```
div.content {
height: 500px;
width: 80%;
margin: 2em auto;
}

div.wrapp {
width: 55%;
margin: 2em auto;
height: 250px;
position: relative;
top: 65%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
div.multiplewrapps {
width: 55%;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Not made for safari sadly. So if you want to use multiple paragraphs on your page just change the class to "multiplewrapps" and it will apply that css code! =) Glad I could help!